# How to detect if I have scrolled to the right of the Div with useRef in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a button disabled. I have a div which overflows in the X (horizontal direction). I want to disable the scroll right button and scroll left button when a user cannot further scroll left or right respectively.

So far I've accomplished the scrollLeft part by the following.

```js
    const cardContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    const [ScrollPos, setScrollPos] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {

        const handleScroll = () => {
            if (cardContainerRef.current === null) return;
            // console.log(cardContainerRef.current?, " ", cardContainerRef.current?.scrollLeft)
            setScrollPos(cardContainerRef.current?.scrollLeft);

        }

        cardContainerRef.current?.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)

        return () => {
            cardContainerRef.current?.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        }
    }, [])

    <button
                        style={{
                            opacity: ScrollPos === 0 ? "50%" : "100%"
                        }}
                        onClick={() => {
                            if (cardContainerRef.current === null) {
                                return
                            }
                            cardContainerRef.current.scrollLeft -= 200
                        }}
                    >
                        {
                            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
                            <Image src={LeftArrow} alt='Navigators' className='rotate-90' />
                        }
                    </button>
                
<button
                        style={{
                            opacity: (ScrollPos === cardContainerRef.current?.scrollLeft - cardContainerRef.current?.clientWidth) ? "50%" : "100%"
                        }}

                        onClick={() => {
                            if (cardContainerRef.current === null) {
                                return
                            }
                            // console.log(cardContainerRef.current.scrollLeft);
                            cardContainerRef.current.scrollLeft += 200
                        }}>

                        {
                            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
                            <Image src={RightArrow} alt='Navigators' className='-rotate-90' />
                        }
                    </button>
```

I could use some help with the right button, thank you in advance!!

If you want some more info to answer this, please ask it.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen scroll events on your card container and check element scroll state like so:

```
<div ref={cardContainerRef} onScroll={(e) => {
  if (!event.target.scrollLeft) {
    setDisableScrollLeftButton(true);
  } else {
    setDisableScrollLeftButton(false);
  }

  const scrollableWidth = e.target.scrollWidth - e.target.clientWidth;
  if (event.target.scrollLeft === scrollableWidth) {
    setDisableScrollRightButton(true);
  } else {
    setDisableScrollRightButton(false);
  }

}}>
</div>
```